# Replacing spaces in regular expression-match with underscores

Tags: php, regex

I want the link destination to have underscores instead of spaces between the words in the link address.

My code looks like:

```
preg_replace("/\[\[(.+?)\]\]/", '<a href="/XLab/?document=$1">$1</a>', $document->content)
```

The first occurance of $1 should have underscores instead of spaces.

Thank you!

Comment: What does this code do currently? I see nothing to do with underscores currently. Also no idea what `$document->content` has, so it'll be hard to test. Likely `preg_replace_callback` could be used with `str_replace(' ', '_', $match[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `preg_replace_callback` since you may not manipulate the backreferences in the `preg_replace` string replacement patterns:

```
$text = "[[Some text]] and [[one more here]]";
echo preg_replace_callback("/\[\[(.+?)]]/", function($m) {
        return '<a href="/XLab/?document=' . str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1]) . '">' . $m[1] . '</a>';
    }, $text);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/AhqgJ).

Here,

- `$m` is the match object containing `$m[0]`, the whole match, and `$m[1]`, the contents between `[[` and `]]`
- `str_replace(' ', '_', $m[1])` replaces each space with `_`. Replace with `preg_replace('~\s+~u', '_', $m[1])` to replace any 1+ whitespace chunks with a single `_`.